# How to define binary string variables in MASM?

Tags: string, assembly, binary, masm, masm32

In c++ I can use define a binary string like this:

```
char v[] = "\xfc\xe8\x89\x00\x00\x00";
```

Now I am trying to do that on MASM, I tried this:

```
v byte fcy, e8y, 89y, 00y, 00y, 00y, 0
```

But MASM show the error "nondigit in number" when assembling. How should I do this in MASM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
v byte 0fch, 0e8h, 089h, 0, 0,0
```

http://webster.cs.ucr.edu/Page_TechDocs/MASMDoc/ProgrammersGuide/Chap_05.htm